# Am I getting my full harddisk capacity?

Tags: hard-disk, external-hdd

Writing `# df -B1` I see my drive listed as

```
/dev/mapper/hd 4961441058816  755834880 4710619553792   1% /media/externalhd
```

I guess `4961441058816` is correct. It's listed as 5TB (and not TiB but I never see anything listed as TiB or GiB). 4620.7gb is close enough but I thought I'd ask just to make sure. I did notice when I first plugged it in there was a message (possibly in dmesg) saying that NTFS only had 2TB support.

Comment: Use `df -h` for human readable

Comment: Either the question is malformed or insufficient details are provided on the actual usage.  You actually include more questions than details.  Refer to [Wikipedia's article on `TiB`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tebibyte) to understand the difference.  `TiB` being the proper way of defining disk space.  I'm not sure where you got the information about NTFS being limited to 2TiB but that's inaccurate, at least out of context.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I believe dmesg said I can not use >2TB NTFS partition.

Comment: That is most likely due to your partition table.  A quick Google search gives really good results such as https://carltonbale.com/how-to-break-the-2tb-2-terabyte-file-system-limit/

Comment: @JuliePelletier It looks like I forgot to say it but I formatted it to use ext4 which is how I got the bigger number (4961441058816). I'm fairly certain I am accessing the full drive I thought i'd write a question to make sure.

Comment: Do you understand that NTFS and ext4 are two completely different file systems that can not coexist on the same partition?  It's one or the other.